# Fullscreen keyboard in landscape, flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app that has a dialog with a `TextField` inside it. It works fine in Portrait, but in Landscape, the dialog gets crushed by the keyboard.

I'm trying to achieve this behavior, but I have no clue how to do it

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/421445316617961502/910183568792227930/Screenshot_20211116-170401_WhatsApp.jpg

It is the default in Android, but searching about it in Flutter says something about Flutter not knowing how to handle this view from the keyboard.

Is this true? Is there no way to achieve this in Flutter? Or is there some behavior I'm missing?

Comment: please add code to the question and also what result you are getting?

Comment: It's not something I'm doing, so it's nothing to do with code. It's simply the behavior in the image

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be out of luck, this behaviour you are looking for is the standard Android fullscreen IME, but Flutter devs disabled it without providing any way of enabling it back: https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/3131/files

Right now the best solution would be to create an special widget that detects when the app is in landscape and the keyboard is shown and hide all other UI and show a Flutter text input above it, you can synchronise the inputs by using the same textController and it should work fine